# in_array() not working with two dimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying very simply to use in_array() to check a key is in an array and then echo its value.

```
$array = Array
( 
    [cart_item] => Array 
        ( 
            [0] => Array 
                ( 
                    [product_name] => White Sakura Necktie
                    [id] => 11
                    [product_auto_id] => 556729685
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [product_regular_price] => 95
                    [product_sale_price] => 95
                    [product_image] => 556729680Black_Sakura_Necktie.jpg 
                )
            [1] => Array 
                ( 
                    [product_name] => hhhad ba bhdbh
                    [id] => 10
                    [product_auto_id] => 951790801
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [product_regular_price] => 20
                    [product_sale_price] => 
                    [product_image] => 951790801hhhad_ba_bhdbh_.jpg 
                )
        ) 
)
```

And I have value 556729685 which I want to check that this value exists or not? So I am using in_array() function for this.

```
in_array(556729685, array_keys($array));
in_array(556729685, array_values($array));
in_array(556729685, $array);
```

All above three i have used but result always showing NULL means blank.

I am really frustrated to find the solution. I don't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which will return the values from a single column in the input array as an array.

```
$product_auto_ids = array_column($array['cart_item'], 'product_auto_id');
```

In this case, it would return the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 556729685
    [1] => 951790801
)
```

Then you can use [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like you currently are.

```
in_array(556729685, $product_auto_ids);
```